# Escape character in Docker command line

Tags: docker

I have a docker image in which I want to run the following command :

1. `echo "1" > /tmp/service.cfg`
2. `/bin/bash`

How can I group and escape this command to run it within a docker container :

```
docker run -i -t debian/latest echo "1" > /tmp/service.cfg && /bin/bash
```

The command above doesn't works as it doesn't echo in the desired file first and then give me the hand in a shell...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found the solution, I needed to run the `sh` command with the `-c` flag like this :

```
docker run -i -t debian:latest sh -c 'echo "1" > /tmp/service.cfg && cat /tmp/service.cfg'
```

This returns 1 as expected...