# How to run 2 commands with docker exec

Tags: docker

I need to run 2 commands with docker exec.
I am copying a file out of the docker container and don't want to have to deal with credentials to use something like ssh.
This command copies a file:

```
sudo docker exec boring_hawking tar -cv /var/log/file.log | tar -x
```

But it creates a subdirectory var/log, I want to avoid that so if I could do these in the docker container I should be good:

```
cd /var/log ; tar -cv ./file.log
```

How can I make docker exec run 2 commands?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

This led to the answer:  [Escape character in Docker command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274326/escape-character-in-docker-command-line)
I ended up doing this:

```
sudo docker exec boring_hawking \
    bash -c 'cd /var/log ; tar -cv ./file.log' \
    | tar -x
```

So it works by, sort of, running the one bash command with a parameter that is the 2 commands I want to run.

Comment: If you have got double quotations inside the command, then you can do as such `-c "cd /var/log; tar -cv \"$1\""` if the file is at parameter 1.

Answer (score 57):

For anyone else who stumbles across this and wants a different way to specify multiple commands in order to execute a more complex script:

```
cat <<EOF | docker exec --interactive boring_hawking sh
cd /var/log
tar -cv ./file.log
EOF
```

Comment: This is a very nice readable solution when you want to execute a more complex script. It deserves more up votes ;)

Comment: i'm getting a `the input device is not a TTY` error with this method

Comment: The `--interactive` is supposed to take care of that, if that is not the case then I'm not sure what is going on without having broader context on how you are using this.

Comment: @Roy try the -t ?

Comment: Note: If your script contains variables, you need to escape the `$`. For example: `for i in {1..5}; do echo "Welcome \$i times"; done` (use `\$i` in the echo!)

Comment: Take care not to specify the `-t` flag, just `-i` or `--interactive`, otherwise you'll have the `the input device is not a TTY` error.

Answer (score 49):

Quite often, the need for several commands is to change the working directory — as in the OP's question.

For that, docker now has a `-w` option to specify the working directory. E.g. in the present case

```
docker exec -w /var/log boring_hawking tar -cv ./file.log
```

Answer (score 6):

If anyone else came here for the awesome answer, but also wants a better way to solve OP's original problem (OP's OP..?) to copy a file out of a docker container, there is now a `docker cp` command that will do this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/