# Fail to execute multiple commands with apptainer exec

Tags: apptainer

I follow the answers here [How to run 2 commands with docker exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416286/how-to-run-2-commands-with-docker-exec) to run 2 commands with apptainer exec:

```
apptainer exec myPython/ bash -c 'activate virtual environment; mpiexec -n 2 python3 main.py'
```

But I got the following error messages:

```
[mpiexec@acn93] HYDU_create_process (lib/utils/launch.c:73): execvp error on file srun (No such file or directory)
```

Any helps are greatly appreciated.