How to list contents of docker container from Windows?
I have a running container which I can interact with, but when I try to list the contents of the container via these commands it fails.
I tried:
docker exec mycontainer bash ls /

/usr/bin/ls: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
docker exec mycontainer ls /

cannot access 'C:/Program Files/Git/': No such file or directory

update:
My intention is to test that a file exists with a single command that I can then run from a test runner to expect output.
docker exec mycontainer bash test -f scripts/populate-args && echo 'file exists'

/usr/bin/test: /usr/bin/test: cannot execute binary file
Note: I have already written permission to read write to this file and can run it when I interact with the docker container via
docker exec -it mycontainer bash

Is it a Windows container or a Linux container (running under WSL2)?

@HansKilian Its a linux container running on windows host

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [su], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

@tripleee Bash script is programming.

Writing actual Bash scripts is programming (visit my profile if you doubt that I am familiar with Bash) but running an individual command interactively isn't.

@tripleee I intend to write some bash script but this is the first step. I can't do anything at this point because its failing. I could extend my question with some bash script for the purpose of being extra tedious

The other problem is that your question contains way too few details. I'll be happy to remove my close vote if you [edit] it to provide the information you have now only supplied in comments, and probably a magnitude more in order to actually document what you have and how exactly it isn't working. Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Vaguely thanks for the update, but the question still contains no information about what operating systems you are running or where the error message is coming from. Anyway, the proper way to write that is docker exec mycontainer bash -c 'test -f scripts/populate-args && echo "file exists"' (or perhaps, marginally more efficiently, docker exec mycontainer test -f scripts/populate-args && echo "file exists" assuming you have 'sh', '-c' in ENTRYPOINT; but then also assuming your host operating system isn't braindead)

@tripleee thanks for the answer but I need to output that to my host command line.

That's not an answer, that's a comment. I don't understand what you mean by "output that to my host command line". But if your main problem is that you used bash instead of bash -c, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416286/how-to-run-2-commands-with-docker-exec

@tripleee - I've looked at your that link which you claim is a duplicate, but my question is on using a 'windows' host. That example uses 'sudo' which is linux. Regarding your experience of bash - having looked at your previous answers I can see you are well versed and experienced in this subject. I am not. Closing my question was unnecessary. Regarding the 'ls' command not being 'programming' is being pedantic.  I have answered my own question for anyone else with the same problem to help novices like me in this area.

The syntax for docker exec is the same regardless of the host operating system. I'll note that I have not single-handedly voted to close this; there is a consensus of multiple users. And again, even if we agree that running a command is "programming", I would still vote to close as lacking sufficient details.

Maybe, but the guides I've read say you can do docker exec containername ls / . Which fails

That seems like a useful and relevant question, but your question doesn't ask specifically about that, and again, that's probably more suitable for [su]. My vague speculation is that Docker for Windows does something weird if you pass in / as a command-line argument on Windows, but I fortunately have no way to test that.

ok Thanks to @triplee I've managed to find my answer:
To list the contents I didn't need to use the word 'bash'.
Also using the path '/' failed.
Success - Listing the files in the root directory of the container and output to windows host terminal
Fixes problem (Omit the forward slash for the root / if excluding 'bash')

docker exec mycontainer ls

OR

docker exec mycontainer bash -c 'ls /'

bin
boot
dev
docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
etc
home
...

Actual:
Success - testing file exits and output to windows host terminal

docker exec mycontainer test -f missingfile && echo "file ex
ists"


Expected output: empty


docker exec mycontainer test -f scripts/populate-args.sh && echo "file exists"


Expected output: file exists

