# How to escape docker tag for a container?

Tags: docker, liquibase

I'm trying to use docker image for running liquibase, I need to run tag command, something like `tag 0.1.0` , but docker doesn't understand that its entrypoint argument and not `docker tag`.

DockerFile: https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/tree/master/docker/liquibase/postgres

Please let me know how to solve this!

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/liquibase/ -e "LIQUIBASE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://database-1.******.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/dbtest" -e "LIQUIBASE_USERNAME=postgres" -e "LIQUIBASE_PASSWORD=******" webdevops/liquibase:postgres tag 0.1.0
/entrypoint: line 172: exec: tag 0.1.0: not found
```

Comment: Have you tried what is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274326/escape-character-in-docker-command-line

Comment: Can you include enough information to reproduce the issue (for example, the actual `Dockerfile`) in the question itself?  That error message looks like it's coming from the `/entrypoint` script in the image, and including the content around line 172 of that file would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a docker expert by any means, but it seems like the `tag` command is not listed in the commands available in `entrypoint.sh` I think if you added it to [line 79](https://github.com/webdevops/Dockerfile/blob/d35192b76167e04af04c2054cda62dceb6c35325/docker/liquibase/postgres/conf/bin/entrypoint.sh#L79) that would help. Otherwise, when running from the command line you would need to execute your command line with `liquibase tag 0.1.0` rather than just `tag 0.1.0`